# Is it possible to run a react native project without node modules folder

Tags: react-native

please tell me is it possible to run a react native project without node modules.

I have cloned a project from git now there are no node modules in this project folder.

when i tried to give 'npm install' node modules are supposed to be installed but i got a meassage like 'up to date'.

please tell me what is going on

Comment: Please include the link of the git project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely not possible. For a start, [react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native) itself is an npm package, with 52 direct dependencies, so running `npm install` should install at least 53 packages (in fact it installs much more, because every dependency also has dependencies, and so on).

However, you can have a project on which you can have `npm install` that outputs `up to date`: this is the case for zero-dependencies projects. But a `react-native` project can't be one of these.